# error: field ‘nm_creds’ has incomplete type

Tags: c, structure, header-files

What is the correct order for the following structures? It's throwing field has an incomplete type error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct nl_msg
{   
    int         nm_protocol;
    int         nm_flags;
    struct ucred        nm_creds;
    struct nlmsghdr *   nm_nlh;
    size_t          nm_size;
    int         nm_refcnt;
};

struct nl_msg;
struct nl_tree;
struct ucred;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code (*rather, translation unit.*), there's nowhere `struct ucred` is defined.

You need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` MACRO and include [`sys/socket.h`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) header which defines this structure.

[See this online](https://ideone.com/dvsSvh).

Comment: Hi @Sourav,
I 've included. Still I am facing the same error

Comment: @nayabbashasayed Did you define `_GNU_SOURCE `?

Comment: Where you want me to define that. Actually, I've read some other post recommending it.

Comment: Yep.. Working Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Your struct contains a field of type `struct ucred` which has not been defined anywhere.

You need to supply a definition for that type.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fields in your struct `nl_msg`:

```
struct ucred        nm_creds;
```

Has an undefined data type; you have not defined the struct for `ucred` anywhere. You need to define the struct `ucred` somewhere in your code. That is why you get the error:

> *field has an incomplete type error*.

If you are referring to the `socket.h` file, then you need to add the header file to your code that defines this struct:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

EDIT: you also need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` macro.

Comment: It has <linux/socket.h> header file. struct ucred is defined in that header file